# Update datatype for all values of a column in cosmos db

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have data already existing in my table in cosmos db - sql.
I want to change all the data existing in table for column myCol1 into Integer for e.g. 1 in this case:

```
MyTable:
{
"myCol1":"1",
"myCol2":"Hello"
}
```

I tried to change the POJO/repository format to Integer and load the data in my Java application and then resaving these records in DB but it doesn't update the data.

Comment: There's really no built-in way to alter the schema of existing documents as a bulk operation. And changing your POJO won't really impact any existing data. You would need to perform some type of full-collection consumption and related processing, and there are several approaches to this (using Changefeed, for example, might work for you).

Comment: I am having the same issue, any solution on this?